# Angular onpush change detection strategy with primitive values

Tags: angular, typescript

may be I am misunderstanding the changeDetection strategy in angular.

Here is Description:

- I have 2 Sibling components (S1 and S2)
- Think both the components as widget on which some graphical data being displayed
- When loaded I want to display data on both the component initially. (For this I am using behaviour subject)
- From S1 I want to notify S2 to trigger a http service call. (I have used behaviour subject and calling .next on click of a button in S1. I am subscribing to same observable in S2 to get the data)
- My S2 component is registered with `onPush` change detection strategy.
- I am using `loading` text while http service call is in progress and then removing the text after complete using `ngIf` using primitive variable `this.loading=true/false`

Now My problem is when App loads initially I can see `loading...` text on S2 widget and then data gets populated.

But when I click on the `notify sibling` button in S1, it does triggers the service call but while http is in process I can't see `loading...` text.

Here is code of S1 :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MessagingService } from '../messaging.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _sendMessage: MessagingService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  notifyChild() {
    this._sendMessage.notifySibling();
  }
}
```

Here code of S2 :

```
import { Component, OnInit,ChangeDetectionStrategy ,ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import { MessagingService } from '../messaging.service';
import { switchMap, takeUntil, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  public loading = true;
  public myData: any;
  constructor(private _receiveMessage: MessagingService,private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._receiveMessage.registerNotification().pipe(
      switchMap(res => {
        this.loading = true;
        /** Simulate http call below  */
        return of([res.data]).pipe(
          delay(5000)
        )
      })
    ).subscribe(response => {
      this.myData = response;
      this.loading = false;
      this.cd.markForCheck();
    })
  }

}
```

Note: I have added `this.cd.markForCheck();` in subscription. If i comment this like I am only seeing `loading...` and no data being displayed

Messaging Service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessagingService {
  public _notify = new BehaviorSubject({ data: "initial Call" });
  public notify = this._notify.asObservable();
  constructor() { }

  notifySibling() {
    this._notify.next({ data: 'call from sibling' });
  }
  registerNotification() {
    return this.notify;
  }

}
```

Full working example is published on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fbgjit?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsibling%2Fchild.component.ts)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`OnPush` strategy run check only when `@Input` property is changed if you want to run it in async context you have to call `this.cd.markForCheck()` yourself before request and after request.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._receiveMessage.registerNotification().pipe(
      switchMap(res => {
        this.loading = true;
        /** note this */
        this.cd.markForCheck();
        return of([res.data]).pipe(
          delay(1000)
        )
      })
    ).subscribe(response => {
      this.myData = response;
      this.loading = false;
      this.cd.markForCheck();
    })
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmvmgz

*english ain't my native language :(*

Comment: ok so I believe adding `this.cd.markForCheck();` is the only option if i am updating primitive values in async context>

Comment: I tried this and was working previously :)  ..just wanted to clear if this is the only solution . I Thought I was doing something wrong.

Comment: i think you could move this request to parent component and pass loading and response to sibling using @Input parameters or just change detectionStrategy to Default

Comment: I guess using `this.cd.markForCheck();` is not hack.. even `async` pipe behind the scene uses `markForCheck` so its safe to use

Comment: it is safe as long as you know what you are doing :P